# scrapping in python using selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriver

I want to fetch transaction, volume & uaw from historical activity graph for last 7days day wise from url  https://dappradar.com/polygon/games/aavegotchi. This graph is canvas image how can i scrape the data from this graph and store data points?

here is the image of source code & graph  [image: this is image for data]
[image: image for source code]

Answer (score 0):

To get the data from the graph to a DataFrame you can use their API URL:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests


url = 'https://dappradar.com/v2/api/dapp/polygon/games/aavegotchi/chart/week?currency=USD'

data = requests.get(url).json()

df = pd.DataFrame(data['csvData']['data'])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
          day   uaw  volume  transactions
0  2023-01-05  1428       0         15718
1  2023-01-04  1447       0         15569
2  2023-01-03  1362       0         16009
3  2023-01-02  1334       0         15619
4  2023-01-01  1244       0         13942
5  2022-12-31  1396       0         15260
6  2022-12-30  1434       0         16893
```

Comment: This api doesn't gives correct data they need cookie header for correct data when I am trying this I am getting response as {'series': [{'name': 'Users', 'data': [10000000000, 10000000000, 10000000000, 10000000000, 10000000000, 10000000000, 10000000000, 10000000000, 10000000000, 10000000000, 10000000000, 10000000000, 10000000000, 10000000000, 10000000000, 10000000000, 10000000000, 10000000000, 10000000000, 10000000000, 10000000000]}
after logging data